How to Uninstall Local [HuggingFace] AI Model off of VS Code
I'm relatively new to programming with VS Code & Hugging Face models, so I apologize if this question has a rather facile solution. I ran the google/madlad400-3b-mt & google/madlad400-10b-mt models' respective sample usage scripts (to initialize), which took a while to run (on my CPU/GPU?) and also took up an ample amount of computer storage space. The task that I was attempting to work on no longer neccesitates the use for these models; I want to know where the long initialization downloads are stored so that I can delete them. Below is a sample screenshot of  the phenomena that I am refering to in case there is better fitting nomenclature: Output.
Thank you!
I do not know how to manually find the location of these files and am not sure of their capabilities.

can you not run find / -type f -name '*.safetensors' ?

The location depends on your OS and setup, so it's hard to give definitive advice.
Search your computer for those filenames you've posted.
They'll be likely in a huggingface folder, in a subfolder named after the model. Then delete that relevant folder.

Thank you, I should have specified that I am on the latest Mac OS.

In that case, open ~/.cache/huggingface/hub should open the correct cache folder.
